# Do I need to have multiple event hub consumer groups for multiple sinks?

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub

I am receiving streaming data from eventhub and I am having 4 types of data coming from eventhub.

I am Reading data from event hub on my databricks clusters as :

```
ehConf = {}
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(EVENT_HUB_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_STRING)
ehConf['eventhubs.consumerGroup'] = 'ConsumerGroup_1'

spark_df = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(**ehConf).load()
```

In message property I have the type of message, so I am separating the data using the spark where function something like below:

```
df_type_A = spark_df.select(col("body")).where(spark_df.properties["msgType"]=="TypeA")
df_type_B = spark_df.select(col("body")).where(spark_df.properties["msgType"]=="TypeB")
df_type_C = spark_df.select(col("body")).where(spark_df.properties["msgType"]=="TypeC")
df_type_D = spark_df.select(col("body")).where(spark_df.properties["msgType"]=="TypeD")
```

And then writing the data to different sinks something like below:

```
df_type_A.writeStream\
    .format("text")\
    .trigger(processingTime='10 seconds')\
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/type_A/Checkpoint")\
    .option("path", "/mnt/type_A/Data")\
    .start()

df_type_B.writeStream\
    .format("text")\
    .trigger(processingTime='10 seconds')\
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/type_B/Checkpoint")\
    .option("path", "/mnt/type_B/Data")\
    .start()

df_type_C.writeStream\
    .format("text")\
    .trigger(processingTime='10 seconds')\
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/type_C/Checkpoint")\
    .option("path", "/mnt/type_C/Data")\
    .start()

df_type_D.writeStream\
    .format("text")\
    .trigger(processingTime='10 seconds')\
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/type_D/Checkpoint")\
    .option("path", "/mnt/type_D/Data")\
    .start()
```

As I understand spark follows lazy execution and for multiple sink it will be create 4 different dag graphs. Microsoft says **"it's recommended that there's only one active receiver on a partition per consumer group."** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features)

**To function everything properly, do I need to create 4 different consumer groups on event hub and write separate jobs for each Type(A, B, C, D) OR one consumer group is enough ?**

**If creating multiple consumer groups is the only option, is it possible to avoid it and do the same task efficiently ?**

Edit : I tried using single consumer group for my 4 jobs but it didn't worked. It is throwing my New receiver with higher epoch_id with higher epoch of '0' is created hence current receiver 'spark-driver-14' with epoch '0' is getting disconnected. If you are recreating the receiver, make sure a higher epoch is used

Comment: Hi Tizen, feel free to [accept any answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it was of any help to you. If it isn't, feel free to ask for details.

Answer (score 1):

A consumer group is another view over the same data. It is not a concept that allows you to route message to a specific consumer group. Each consumer group processes all the message of all partitions. I think the graph below shows this well:

[image]

(Taken from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#consumer-groups))

Now, regarding this:

> it's recommended that there's only one active receiver on a partition per consumer group

A receiver takes a lock on the partition it is reading for a specific consumer group. If multiple receivers are reading from the same partition and consumer group they will compete over acquiring the lock. That's inefficient and that is why it is advices to have a single active receiver per partition per consumer group.

To me, your approach seems valid as it is. No need for multiple consumer groups.